# Reflect svg using css

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` containing an svg logo inside.

This is my logo example:

[image]

I need to place the logo in this way:

[image]

Now this is my result:

[image]

How can I reflect the logo?

My code:

```
<div className="relative">
  <div
    style={{
      transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
    }}
  >
    {mySvg}
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks very much

Comment: You're probably rotating it clockwise. Try rotating it by 270 degrees and you should get your desired output.

Answer (score 5):

You might try to rotate it counter-clockwise:

```
transform: 'rotate(-90deg)'
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform